# Storing a Boolean from a Keyword

Tags: robotframework

I have a task where my Keyword returns `True` or `False`.
When I run this .robot-script it halts the test if the Keyword is False, telling me the test `|FAIL|`. I dont want it to halt. I want it to store the Boolean in a variable so I can use that boolean in a IF-statement

```
*** Task ***
${BooleanValue} = Keyword

IF ${BooleanValue} == False
 etc etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Run Keyword And Return Status](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status):

```
${BooleanValue} =    Run Keyword And Return Status   Keyword
```

Comment: OK that seems to work! But it still generated an error. But the overall test worked.
`[ ERROR ] AttributeError: Evaluation of Response Payload Contains Failed`.

I guess that is from the Boolean Value "False"?

Comment: @Aard You could try the old syntax `Run Keyword If   not ${BooleanValue}`. If you need multiple statements after that, use `Run Keywords` to combine them.